# How can I check to see if user has execute permissions?

Tags: c, linux, unix, permissions, solaris

I wish to know how to check if the "user" (other than who is running this program)
has execute permissions on a file ? [C api]

I have looked at "access" it gives information with respect to the caller.

I am looking for something like :-

```
"<cmd> <user_name> <file_name>"
```

here I am trying to get if `<user_name>` has execute permissions for `<file_name>` ?

I am looking C api ?

Possible solution :- I am using the following algo to get this information

```
boolean_t
is_user_has_execute_permissions(char *run_as_user)
{
        /* Check world execute permission */
        if ((cmd_stat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) == S_IXOTH) {
                return (TRUE);
        }

        /* group id for run_as_user */
        getpwnam_r(run_as_user, &pw, buf, passwd_len);

        /* Check group execute permission */
        if ((cmd_stat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) == S_IXGRP) {
                if (pw->pw_gid == cmd_stat.st_gid)
                        return (TRUE);
        }

        return (FALSE);
}
```

Did anyone see any error in this one ?

Comment: @Arpit Is a solution in bash acceptable?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you are looking for a C API function or for an external Unix command to do that.

Comment: Yes, I need a C API for this ? I think there is no such api and I have to check for group and world execute permissions and then check if the user belongs to either of these section.

Comment: @Arpit, see below.  the stat system call or the fstat library routine are what you need.  BTW, if there were no such API, how would `ls` find the file permissions?

Comment: @CharlieMartin "ls" checks for group or others permissions not for a user. right ?

Comment: If your process can run as root, then probaqbly the most reliable way is to just `setuid()` to the user in question and call `euidaccess()`. You can try checking the permissinos yourself, but there are more complex scenarios like ACLs or other access policies like through SELinux.

Comment: Yes, the model of UNIX discretionary access controls is somewhat simplistic. While it is easy to figure out the permissions using the stat and system user database, the real case can be much more complex. You're really better off just handling errors accessing the file

Comment: @Arpit: no, your code is wrong. You have to move from specific to more general checks: uid, than group, than others. Otherwise, you miss for example the case when the owner of the file removed the x-bit for himself.

Comment: @fork0, my assumption is if the file has "world" execute permission then any one can run it, even if the owner doesn't have execute permission set?

Comment: @Arpit: That's not how even basic permissions work. They're checked in order of User, Group, Others. Whichever applies first is used. You can check this out by creating a file and then `chmod u-r file`. Even if others have read permission, you don't.

Comment: Ok, I checked just now.. you are right here. I will check in order only.

Answer (score 2):

You need the call stat(2), which returns the permission bits, for the owner of the file, the owner group, and the others. Than you have to find out the id of the user you're interested in and ids its groups: see getpwent(3) and getgrouplist(3). The first which match, will give the resulting permissions.

Comment: For the record: testing for the current user is much easier: access(1)

Comment: err... access(2), it's a syscall

Comment: `stat(2)` is not enough. Both Linux and Solaris support POSIX file ACLs.

Comment: Yes, see the comment from @FatalError above. To support all available access controls (UNIX, SELinux, TOMOYO, Yama, not counting the ones not present in the official kernel) will make the solution really complex, if not impossible

Comment: access(2) and euidaccess(2) work with all of them, though. Assuming you have root on the system, the @FatalError's suggestion is probably the most convenient.

Answer (score -1):

From the command line, you can use an Awk program easily enough.  Something like

```
ls -l filename | awk -F '{ if (substring($1,3,1) == "x" exit(0); exit(1)}'
```

will set the return code to 0 if it's found, 1 if it's not.

From a C program, you want to use `fstat`.  Basically you open the file

```
int fd = fopen("filename", "r");
```

then get the file stat block with `fstat`

```
fstat(fd, &bufr)
```

and look at `bufr.st_mode`.

Here's a description of [fstat](http://www.warpspeed.com.au/cgi-bin/inf2html.cmd?..%5Chtml%5Cbook%5CToolkt40%5CXPG4REF.INF%20139).

**Update**

I'll note crankily that when the OP originally posted, it wasn't clear the C API was what was desired.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for C API for this.

Comment: @CharlieMartin I think the OP wants to check access permissions for _another user_ (not the current user).

Comment: So?  fstat returns the file's permissions; it doesn't care about the user.  st_uid is the owner's uid; use that.

Comment: -1 -- this is horrible, you can just do `[ -x filename ]` for the shell part and use `access(2)` for the C part. Not to mention that you haven't answered the "other user" part of the question.